# Matplotlib choropleth map plotting two different pieces of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, choropleth

So far I have produced a Choropleth map by:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(32, 16))
ax.axis('off')

df.plot(column='Income Rank', scheme='quantiles', k=7,legend=True, cmap='YlOrRd_r', ax=ax)
ax.annotate(xy=(0.1, .08),  xycoords='figure fraction', horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top'
            ,s='Income deprivation Rank. Lowest rank = most deprived.')
```

which looks like this:
[image]

My DF Looks like this:

```
geometry    Counts  WardCode Ward Name   Income Rank                                                                
POLYGON (())    1545    N09000001   Abbey   3
```

So it plots the rank of each area in relation to income data I have in df. Is it possible for me to plot crimes on this map aswell? I am trying to show the link between low income and high crime rate.. For example, with markers or maybe use a different colour scheme to represent high crime areas? The dataframe with my crimes looks like this:

```
WARDNAME    Counts
0   CENTRAL 3206
1   DUNCAIRN    757
2   BLACKSTAFF  584
```

I also have a df of crimes that have Latitude and Longitude, that looks like this:

```
Crime ID    Date    Longit  Latit   Crime type  Ward Name   Ward Code
0   01  2016-01 -5.886699   54.591309  Theft    CENTRAL N08000313
```

Is the only way I can plot both of these things on the same map by using Folium and plotting the Choropleth with the income values and then plotting the crimes as markers? Or can I do it without folium?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Liam,
do you mind to share (at least a sample of) the data you are using?
Does [this](https://plot.ly/python/maps/) or [this](https://moderndata.plot.ly/visualizing-geo-spatial-data-with-sf-and-plotly/) ccould be useful to you?

Comment: @user32185 added some data about the data frame I am using to plot the current map.. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can call the `plot` method of the other geodataframe, being sure to pass the same Axes object to it.

Comment: @Paul H I was able to do this but the second plot just basically overwrites the first so I can't see any of the ranks anymore, its just the crimes plotted.. Can I reduce one so that I can see both?

Comment: what do you mean by "reduce"? Are these both polyon layers? I would plot the ranks as points in the centroids of the polygons with a higher z-order than the first set of polygons.

Comment: @PaulH the polygons are the areas - I just want to be able to plot both things i.e rank of income and crime count.(as seen in the dfs above.) how would I go about plotting the ranks as points in the centroids rather than the way I have done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For choropleth maps with 2 overlaying layers of polygons, you need to use (semi or) transparent plots on top layer. Let me demonstrate with this example. You need to install geopandas to run this.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load world data (provided with geopandas)
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# select some countries (for top layer plots)
brazil = world[world.name == u'Brazil']
russia = world[world.name == u'Russia']

# grouping countries by continents for base layer
world = world[['continent', 'geometry']]  # for grouping purposes, take 2 columns
continents = world.dissolve(by='continent')  # only column 'geometry' is retained; no aggregated attribute

# plot world's continents first as base layer
ax1 = continents.plot(figsize=(12, 8), cmap='Set2')

# plot other polygons on top of the base layer
# 'facecolor' = 'None' specifies transparent area
# plot Brazil at upper level (zorder=11) using 'hatch' as symbol
# higher value of zorder causes the plot on top of layers with lower values
kwarg3s = {'facecolor': 'None', 'edgecolor': 'green', 'linewidth': 1.5, 'hatch': '|||'}
brazil.plot(zorder=11, ax=ax1, **kwarg3s)

# plot Russia at upper level using 'hatch' as symbol
kwarg4s = {'facecolor': 'None', 'edgecolor': 'red', 'linewidth': 0.5, 'hatch': 'xx'}
russia.plot(zorder=11, ax=ax1, **kwarg4s)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:
[image]